# How can I paste text to a pastebin site through API's HTTP POST using a bookmarklet?

Tags: bookmarklet

I want to paste some text to a pastebin site through the site's API.

As I have figured out (I have limited knowledge of programming) I need two things: First to process the selected text and then to post it via HTTP POST to the pastebin site.

I tried to do this...

```
javascript:'<body%20onload="document.forms[0].submit()"><form%20method="post"%20action="http://sprunge.us"><input%20type="hidden"%20name="sprunge"%20value="+ document.getSelection() +"></form>'
```

....which (you guessed it!) returns to me EVERY TIME a page in which the selected text being "+ document.getSelection() +".

Any help?

Comment: If you find a solution helpful, please either vote up or except that solution as the answer to your question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a form programmatically, add the fields required and then post -- all in JavaScript.

Here is an example -- you will at least have to change the URL and the fieldname:

```
<a href="
    javascript:(function(){
        var myform = document.createElement('form');
        myform.method='post';

        /* change this URL: */
        myform.action='http://my-example-pastebin.com/submit.php';

        /* The goodies go here: */
        var myin=document.createElement('input');
        /* Change the fieldname here: */
        myin.setAttribute('name','fieldname_for_pasted_text');
        myin.setAttribute('value',document.getSelection());
        myform.appendChild(myin);

        /* If you need another field for username etc: */
        myin=document.createElement('input');
        myin.setAttribute('name','some_field_1');
        myin.setAttribute('value','some_field_value_1');
        myform.appendChild(myin);

        myform.submit();
    })()
">Bookmarklet for posting selected text to an online pastebin</a>
```

The above compacted without comments and linebreaks:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var myform = document.createElement('form'); myform.method='post'; myform.action='http://my-example-pastebin.com/submit.php'; var myin=document.createElement('input'); myin.setAttribute('name','fieldname_for_pasted_text'); myin.setAttribute('value',document.getSelection()); myform.appendChild(myin); myin=document.createElement('input'); myin.setAttribute('name','some_field_1'); myin.setAttribute('value','some_field_value_1'); myform.appendChild(myin); myform.submit();})()">Bookmarklet for posting selected text to an online pastebin</a>
```

I'm not familiar with *sprunge.us*, but if you've got the URL and fieldname right in your example, you could get this to work by search-replace:

- http://my-example-pastebin.com/submit.php → http://sprunge.us/
- fieldname_for_pasted_text → sprunge

You should also remove the second field (some_field_1, somefield_value_1) included in my example.